# What is the meaning of defined a method by using :: operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For example:

```
class A
   def A::f
   end
end
```

What is A::f ?
I suppose it is neither class method nor instance method...

Answer (score 3):

Using the double colons creates a class method. You can see this by doing a simple test:

```
class A 
  def A::f 
    puts "Called A::f"
  end 
end

puts "A.public_methods:"
puts A.public_methods(false)
puts

a = A.new

puts "a.public_methods:"
puts a.public_methods(false)
puts

puts "Attempt to call f"
A.f
a.f
```

Output:

```
A.public_methods:
f
allocate
new
superclass

a.public_methods:

Attempt to call f
Called A::f
NoMethodError: undefined method ‘f’ for #<A:0x0000010084f020>
```

Comment: It is rather uncommon to define (or call) methods using `::`.

Comment: You can define class methods also using `self` : `def self.f ...`

Answer (score 1):

http://marcricblog.blogspot.com/2007/11/ruby-double-colon.html